# Meteor : Trying to update values from client side to server side DB with auto publish off

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am working on Password Reset functionality. I have user id , new password and Token at Client side. I want to update new password at Server side . But my AUTOPUBLISH is OFF. How can i update records on server side?? with "AUTOPUBLISH" as OFF

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Changing password has nothing to do with `autopublish`. Autopublish package is for getting all the available data without any subscription.

There is another package `insecure` which enables you to write on client side. If you have removed that package, you still would be able to change password with token. This is all handled by the `accounts-password` package.

[See Docs for the usage](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-changePassword)